# Is the new question filter effective?

Tags: discussion, questions

We introduced a filter a couple of days ago that stops people from asking questions if they historically posted poorly scoring stuff. (Stack Overflow ONLY)

For those that lurk around the ["new question" list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest), have you noticed that the quality has improved in some tangible way in the last day?

Comment: Doesn't that go against other things I've read on this site about letting the question be judged for itself not on history of the user?

Comment: @MrX Yes. It does. And for a select few users I am *so* in favor of it.

Comment: @mrx: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system) for the background story.

Comment: Just a question: So if they post high-voted answers, they'll be given the permission to ask again?

Comment: @Georg thanks for the link, I can see the motivation, it does feel like the start of a slippery slope though.

Comment: @waiwai ... yes

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say. Perhaps just a little.

But frankly the general questions stream from earnest, well meaning users who are trying hard has never  been really great. I mean, it's [Sturgeon's Law](http://www.jargon.net/jargonfile/s/SturgeonsLaw.html), right. At best this is going to skim off the few extra percent of crap from really problematic users.

Comment: looking it the last 10 pages (50 per page) I'm only seeing 1 in 50 negative scoring questions. I remember this used to be a lot higher in the past... I guess Ill have to wait for more data and run stats